# Derivative of Log Likelihood Function

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am trying to maximize a particular log likelihood function and I am stuck on the differentiation step.

The function is as follows:

$$l(\mu, \sigma ^{2})=-\dfrac{n}{2}\ln\sigma^{2} - \dfrac{1}{2\sigma^{2}} \sum ^{n}_{i=1}(x_{i}-\mu b_{i})^{2}$$

I cannot figure out how to get the partial with respect to $\mu$  with the summation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a normal composite fuction, you just have to remember to keep the summation sign.
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mu} \sum (x_i - \mu b_i)^2 = 2 \sum (-b_i) (x_i - \mu b_i)
$$
Compare with:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (a-bx)^2 = -2b(a-bx)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial\mu}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i(x_i-\mu b_i).
$$